# python range() with duplicates?

Tags: python, list, range

Everybody knows that a list of numbers can be obtained with `range` like this;:

```
>>> list(range(5))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If you want, say, 3 copies of each number you could use:

```
>>> list(range(5)) * 3
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But is there an easy way using `range` to repeat copies like this instead?

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

Examples:

```
sorted(list(range(5)) * 3)   # has unnecessary n * log(n) complexity
[x//3 for x in range(3*5)]   # O(n), but division seems unnecessarily complicated
```

Comment: Even though you say you don't want it, sorted(range(5)*3) looks pretty elegant to me ;)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do:

```
>>> [i for i in range(5) for _ in range(3)]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

the `range(3)` part should be replaced with your number of repetitions...

BTW, you should use generators

---

Just to make it clearer, the `_` is a variable name for something you don't care about (any name is allowed).

This list comprehension uses nested `for` loops and are just like that:

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(3):
        #your code here
```

Comment: the `_` is used in code to show you don't care about what the variable will hold. I only want to loop 3 times but don't care about the index... it's a convention, thought

Comment: the generator i'm talking about is: `(i for i in xrange(5) for j in xrange(3))`

Comment: well, then use the name you like the most! on the generator i gave, it'll not leak the variable. :)

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(x, 3) for x in range(5))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
from itertools import chain, izip
list(chain(*izip(*[xrange(5)]*3)))
```

Gives

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

Leave off the list and you have a generator.

EDIT: or even better (leaves out a function call to izip):

```
list(chain(*([x]*3 for x in xrange(5))))
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a very simple way to do this with a help from **numpy**. Example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.arange(5*3) // 3
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4])
```

With **range** you can do the following:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: x // 3, range(5*3)))
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

Remembering that **//** performs a strict integer division.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from itertools import chain, izip, tee
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(izip(*tee(range(5), 3))))
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

A cool iterator using another approach:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(range(5) * 3).elements()
```

Answer (score -1):

I like to Keep It Simple :)

```
>>> sorted(list(range(5)) * 3)
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import itertools
[x for tupl in itertools.izip(*itertools.tee(range(0,5),3)) for x in tupl]
```

Or:

```
[x for tupl in zip(range(0,5), range(0,5), range(0,5)) for x in tupl]
```